# deleting rows from data frame based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to delete names of the countries which do not belong to EU from a data frame . I applied this part of code:

```
 df=df[df['COUNTRY'].isin(EU)]
```

wheras EU is a list of EU countries

As output I get the df with hidden rows of non EU countries (eg. indexing starts with 6). How can I remove them entirely from my dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If indexing is the issue, you could reset the index after slicing your dataframe.
Like this:

```
df = df[df['COUNTRY'].isin(EU)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out rows with country not in the EU list by using `~` for inversion:

```
df = df[~df['COUNTRY'].isin(EU)]
```